# use of spark job server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ooyala

I am new to spark.
I want know the use to spark job server like ooyala and Livy.
is spark code cannot communicate with HDFS directly.
Do we need a medium like webservice to send and receive data.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ooyala and Livy

Persistent Spark Context or not help you run spark like a http-service which you can request to create or run a spark job directly from a http call instead of calling from command like to run or cronjob for instance.

> is spark code cannot communicate with HDFS directly

No. It can communicate with HDFS directly.

> Do we need a medium like webservice to send and receive data.

Actually ooyala and Livy they return the result by json like you do call in a API. 
So it depends on you build a medium or not.